# Как создать файловую систему FUSE?

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Вопрос даже не по конкретным языкам программирования. Как мне создать FUSE файловую систему?

Как я понимаю, мне надо лишь описать системные вызовы, применимые к файлам вообще. Ну, грубо говоря, пример из C:

```
struct fuse_operations {
    int open(const char* filename, int mode);
    int close(int fd);
    int lgetattr(const char* filename);
    ...
};
```

Только вот что я там должен [о]писать - неясно. Не говоря уже о том, как FUSE "объяснить", что твоя файловая система - не просто образ диска, а архив (fuse-zip) или, того круче, файлы расположены в оперативной памяти (tmpfs, ramfs, cramfs, rootfs). Вот как заставить FUSE "парсить" файлы из архива, или того круче, хранить файлы в ОЗУ?? И что я должен приписывать в `fuse_operations`, как именно мне описывать эти системные вызовы???

Comment: https://github.com/ixtel/vkfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fuse всеравно где вы храните информацию. Драйвер просто транслирует системные вызовы в вашу программу.

Первое что нужно описать это вызов `opendir()`, `readdir()` - тогда отобразится диск с чемто внутри.

Пишите вызовы `open()`, `read()` и сможете читать виртуальные файлы.

Comment: т е, допустим, у меня имеется cpio архив. Чтобы сделать `chmod()`, можно просто распарсить заголовок cpio архива, идущий перед каждым файлом/каталогом/устройством (если знаете как устроен формат архива cpio, поймёте, о чем я), найти в нем значения прав доступа и поменять их, так? Именно такой порядок действий я должен прописать в `fuse_operations.chmod()`???

Comment: до chmod я не доходил если честно, принцип такой